# How to access Rails 3 engine models in rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

In the mail app's rails console (irb), how to access engine's models.

update: Say "team" is my main app and "team_page" is the engine. "team_page" is required in main app in the gemfile through 'gem => "team_page", :path => "local/path/to/team_page"'.
when I go to team's rails console, I couldn't access team_page's models.

Comment: Do you run `rails console` on the command line? Then you should have access to the model. Otherwise I think you'll have to spice up your question with some more details.

Answer (score 6):

First you must know the module's name. To help with that, you can run a

```
bundle show team_page
```

to find its directory and explore over there (probably under `lib/team_page.rb`) until 
you see the following definition:

```
module TeamPage
  # ...
end
```

Let's say that the module is called `TeamPage`. Then just **prepend double colon to its name** like this:

```
::TeamPage::SomeModel.some_method
```

Comment: so then how do you modify this to get all models for a given engine?